# $\phi: P \to M$ epimorphism with $P$ projective and another epimorphism $f:R \to M$, then $P = Ker(\phi) + Im(g)$ (g by R projectivity)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I want to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring. Let $P$ and $S$ be $R$-modules, with $P$ being a projective $R$-module. Let $\phi: P \to S$ and $f: R \to S$ be surjective $R$-module homomorphisms. Then $P= \text{Ker}(\phi) + \text{Im}(g)$, where $g:R \to P$ is an $R$-module homomorphism such that $\phi \circ g =f$. (Such a $g$ exists because $R$ is a projective $R$-module. )

So by taking an element $p \in P$ cannot express it as a sum of an element of $Ker(\phi)$ and another element of $Im(g)$. I know there is probably trivial explanation but I really frustrates me not to see it. Thanks!

Comment: @KennyWong Done!! Hope its more clear now and thanks for reading.

Comment: I've edited the statement once more. Could you please read it to check that it captures your intent?

Comment: @KennyWong  Yes it does, thanks!

Comment: I really believe this statement it´s true : /. I´ve seen it a lot in proofs related to projective cover for instance at the end of Proposition 7.2.20  and in the middle of Lemma 7.2.17 of Rings and their Modules by Bland  @KennyWong

Comment: Yes it´s a step in some proofs (that I cannot still understand why it happens). Probably a commutative diagra helps @KennyWong

Comment: Also, in those proofs $P$ with $\phi$ is the projective cover of $M$ but I thinks this doesnt play an important role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is true, and a bunch of hypotheses can be dropped:

Given $p \in P$, since $\phi(p) \in S$ and $f$ is surjective, we know that there exists $r \in R$ such that $\phi(p) = f(r)$.
Hence,
$$
\phi(p-g(r)) = \phi(p) - \phi(g(r)) = \phi(p) - f(r) = 0,
$$
meaning that $p-g(r) \in \ker \phi$. Thus:
$$
p = [p-g(r)]+g(r) \in \ker \phi + \operatorname{im} g.
$$